# jquery context menu and asp update panel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

i am using jquery context menu on a div inside an update panel. i read that i should be using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to register the script, and that is what i did.

on partial post back the menu appears on the screen even without right clicking on the div. Moreover if i issued a right click on the div the contextMenu is launched as it normally would.

Comment: Please post your code and asp.net markup.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like just a styling issue, you need to specifyin your CSS that the contextMenu is hidden by default, otherwise it'll work, but also show up *before* you clicked to show it, which is what you describe.

If the menu is for example this:

```
<div class="contextMenu">.....</div>
```

Make sure you have corresponding CSS to hide it, like this:

```
.contextMenu { display: none; }
```

This will keep it hidden until you right click to show it :)